# first-child doesn't work here. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add classes via jQuery. Funny thing is, "last-child" works but "first-child" doesn't. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

```
$("#testimonials-content article:first-child").addClass("first");
$("#testimonials-content article:last-child").addClass("last");
```

So, in that example, the second line works. That is, the class gets added in the markup. However, nothing happens for the first line.

Comment: can you post your html structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't actually want `:first` instead of `:first-child` ?

There's a very important distinction between the two.

Comment: Likewise for `:last` and `:last-child`

Comment: I want to target the first `article` under `#testimonials-content`. Should I be using `:first` instead of `:first-child`?

Comment: You got it. :first-child will return all elements which are the first child of their parent. So if you have anything inside of #testimonials-content that comes before the element you're looking for, it won't get what you want. You should also be using :last instead of :last-child (assuming I'm correctly understanding the selection you want to make)

Comment: I can't seem to find any reference to `:first`, only `:first-of-type`.